# Spring boot - init dataSources before anything else

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, spring-config

I have 2 configuration class one with datasources configuration and the other is my 
`WebSecurityConfig` that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.
I want to load DB values to be used in `WebSecurityConfig`, so I need to finish initing the datasources before `WebSecurityConfig`.

OracleConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle")
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class OracleConfiguration {
   //data source beans...
}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
//security configs like SAML...
}
```

And Still when I debugging, the code in `WebSecurityConfig` runs before the data sources init, datasource init example(inside `OracleConfiguration`)

```
@Bean
@Primary
DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
     //Init
    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setURL(url);
    dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
    dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put dataSource to some bean parameter in WebSecurityConfig. In this case beans in webSecurityConfig will depend from dataSource bean in OracleConfiguration. I think it will work.